# What is the max file size allowed by the system?

Tags: file, unix, operating-system, system, inode

I am given this information, but am not sure how to approach this problem:

```
Double-Indirect Addressing

Disk block size = 1k
File Point is 64 bits (8 bytes)
Block can hold 128 file pointers
Inode holds 8 double-indirect entries
```

Any sort of explanation or starting point would be much appreciated...I am very confused.

Comment: Draw an inode map assuming each inode can hold 4 pointers instead of 128, that keeps things clearer. Now look how many blocks you can point to, if you limit yourself to two levels of indirection (so top inode, level 1 inodes, and level 2 inodes)

Answer (score 0):

File pointer 64 means you can have a file that is has a maximum offset of the the largest number that a 64 bit unsigned number can have.  In theory.  In practice you don't have disk space for

```
2^64 -1 bytes of file data  + 1 byte for a null terminator
```

The `df -h` command  will show you the max available free space you have on your filesystems.  Select one for the big file.

PS: `2^64 -1: 18446744073709551615`

The reason for this is that up until recently filesystems were limited to files of size 2^32 -1 bytes.
As hardware changed, "largefile" extensions for accessing files larger than that were cobbled together on 32 bit systems.   With 64 bit processors filesize using 64 bit pointers became commonly available.

Comment: Files don't have null terminators.